# Check if 2 minimum DFA are equivalent

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata, automata, dfa

I have 2 minimized DFA and i need to check if they are equivalent.

If they are equivalent, the problem is to find a efficient comparison of state regardless of different labels. In my case DFA are table, then i need to find the permutation that match the rows of first DFA with rows of second DFA.

I thought also about to have a Breadth-first search of DFA and create the minimum access string to a state and then compare the first list with the second list (this should be regardless of the particular input, for example: 001 and 110 could be interchangeable).

I'm interesting either to direct and inefficient algorithm and to more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: Yes, a BFS should work well, even a DFS would do (you just have to ensure that you run both DFA graphs in the same order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these algorithms:

```
 - Symmetric difference
 - Table-filling algorithm
 - Faster Table-Filling algorithm O(n^2)
 - Hopcroft algorithm
 - Nearly Linear algorithm by Hopcroft and Karp
```

A complete reference is:

- [**Algorithms for testing equivalence of finite automata, with a grading tool for Jflap**](http://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7944&context=theses) - Norton, 2009

I accepted this my answere because the one of @abbaasi is too incomplete.
I will accept any other answer with a significant contribution.

Answer (score 2):

The right approach is to construct another DFA with:
L3=(L1-L2) U (L2-L1)
And test whether L3 is empty or not. If L3 is empty then L1=L2, otherwise L1<>L2

Answer (score 0):

I remeber a minimum DFA is unique. So if you have 2 minimized DFA, I think you only need to check whether they're the same.